# OpenCL Simple "Hello World!" program compiles correctly but spits out garbage when executed

Tags: opencl, archlinux

As the title suggests, I have copied verbatim the `hello.cl` and `hello.c` files from Fixstar's online OpenCL book, at http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/first-opencl-program.html, and cannot get correct output.

I compile the program using 
    `gcc -lOpenCL hello.c -o hello`.

I execute normally with
     `./hello`.

But my output reads something like
     ���.

I run Arch Linux and have installed OpenCL, the headers, and the NVIDIA implementation. I would like to continue learning OpenCL but simply cannot continue if my programs won't run. Does anyone have any ideas on what is occuring? Additionally, if anyone has any advice on how to debug this I would be immensely happy.

EDIT: I was using Nouveau drivers instead of the Nvidia ones. Nouveau does not support OpenCL. This was the problem.

Comment: Have you taken all the steps required to ensure a proper installation? http://www.thebigblob.com/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/. Have you looked at this particular sample that is meant to run on arch linux? http://sublimated.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/an-opencl-hello-world-using-cuda-on-arch-linux/

Comment: Do you have any tutorial applications running correctly on your system?

Comment: No, I don't have any running correctly. I do believe I went through the installation process correctly, as according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GPGPU for OpenCL, and I did see the two sites you recommended anathonline (thanks though), but I believe the issue may be this: The Nvidia implementation is available in extra/opencl-nvidia. It only supports Nvidia GPUs running the nvidia kernel module (nouveau does not support OpenCL yet).

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it so other people can find it when the come looking. Oh, and add the appropriate tags like arch-Linux in addition to OpenCL to your question because that's relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouveau does NOT support OpenCL yet. Replace nouveau with nvidia and check to make sure `libcl`, `libcl-headers`, and `opencl-nvidia` are all correctly installed.